# How to handle a dictionary with multiple key values in swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary

If I have a dictionary like the one shown below, how can I break up the values so I can use the color, content, etc separately? How do I convert the the dictionary to a struct? I am not sure where to go from here...

```
(key: "comment2", value: {
    color = grape;
    content = "yeah ";
    date = 563954564;
    icon = referee;
    userName = "That Guy";
})


let comments = messages.childSnapshot(forPath: "comments").value as? [String: Any] ?? [:]



                for comment in comments {

                    struct aComment {
                        let content: String
                        let icon: String
                        let color: String
                        let date: String
                        let userName: String

                        init(comment: [String: Any]) {
                            self.content = comment["content"] as? String ?? ""
                            self.icon = comment["icon"] as? String ?? ""
                            self.color = comment["color"] as? String ?? ""
                            self.date = comment["date"] as? String ?? ""
                            self.userName = comment["userName"] as? String ?? ""
                        }

                    }


                }
```

Comment: Map the dictionary to a struct.

Comment: how would one do that

Comment: You're getting down-voted because your question is unclear, showing us only some ambiguous output, not showing us how you parsed this. A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) But, in answer to your question, I'd suggest you don't really want to. "break up the values", but rather you want a model structure that easily lets you access what you need. But we can't possibly meaningfully answer the question with the information provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Swift’s basic way of mapping. for example we have a view struct in the example above. First, we will add an init method to it.

```
init(with dictionary: [String: Any]?) {
  guard let dictionary = dictionary else { return }
  color = dictionary["color"] as? String
}
```

Then map your object like this:

```
let view = View(dictionary: data["comment2"])
```